# Opensea error: 'AccountData' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: nft, opensea

I am trying to put on sale an NFT in Opensea (mainnet or testnet) and it launching next error. Any idea what i am doing bad? Thanks.

```
error Relay request for `OrderCreateActionModalQuery` failed by the following reasons: 
1. 'AccountData' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been a temporary error. Opensea has already fixed it.

Comment: Hello. Please provide a proof of this solution. For example, a link of the release note stating that and a quote of the part that interests us in this question.